# Docker install.packages R on Ubuntu 22.04 packages not found

Tags: r, dockerfile

I have the docker command to install R packages:

```
RUN R -e "install.packages(c("readxl","zoo","plotly","RcppRoll","shiny","tidyverse"\
,"shinyWidgets","shinythemes","metR","writexl","shinydashboard","lubridate","sjmisc"\
,"DBI","dplyr","dbplyr","odbc"), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
```

I get the error

install.packages(c(readxl,zoo,plotly,RcppRoll,shiny,tidyverse,shinyWidgets,shinythemes,metR,writexl,shinydashboard,lubridate,sjmisc,DBI,dplyr,dbplyr,odbc), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')
Error in install.packages(c(readxl, zoo, plotly, RcppRoll, shiny, tidyverse,  :
object 'readxl' not found
Execution halted

Where is the error? R runs fine without docker.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the problem, but you could try to use single quotes on the package names because they are inside the double quotes overall

Comment: I have try it and it works! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are falling victim to shell quoting, sometimes called shell quoting hell.  The fact that, as you say, "R runs fine without docker" just means you have the right command inside R, but not from the shell.  Witness

```
$ Rscript -e "cat("Hello, world\n")"
Error: unexpected end of input
Execution halted
$
```

but (method 1) escaping quotes works:

```
$ Rscript -e "cat(\"Hello, world\n\")"
Hello, world
$
```

or (method 2) wrapping double quotes in single quotes

```
$ Rscript -e 'cat("Hello, world\n")'
Hello, world
$
```

So I would try

```
RUN R -e 'install.packages(c("readxl","zoo","plotly","RcppRoll","shiny", 
          "tidyverse",    "shinyWidgets","shinythemes","metR","writexl",
          "shinydashboard","lubridate","sjmisc", "DBI", "dplyr", 
          "dbplyr", "odbc"), repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")'
```

As an aside you may also want to look into [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) to have all this done as binaries (!!) on Ubuntu 22.04 or 20.04.

Comment: I have try it and it works! Thanks

Comment: Sorry dirk, I do not find "click on 'up' triangle"

Comment: Look to the left of the beginning of my answer. _Currently_ you a see zero (no votes yet) along with 'up' and 'down' triangle.  That is for up (or down) voting.  For a question you asked you also see a 'checkmark' (or 'tickmark') you can click. There are some rules, you may need at least 10 points to accept if I recall.

Comment: I have done the vote